# I want a glow effect on a div on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a glow effect on a div on hover with jQuery. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="tablerow">  
    <div class="image">
       <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="info">
       <p>
       <span class="heading">the PURSUIT of HAPPYNESS</span><br>       
       <span class="sub">Inspired by a true story.</span><br>
       <span class="data">Chris Gardener finds the "i" in Happiness...</span><p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tablerow{
    width:100%;
    height:185px;
    padding:0;
}
```

I have 8 more divs with the class tablerow on which i want a glow effect(not shadow) on hover with jquery, so needs some help with that. (I have used CSS tables).

Comment: That sounds great. I want a glow effect too, let's collaborate. What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803549/touch-glow-example-with-css-and-jquery-enjoy

Comment: @Ohgodwhy dude i am new to jQuery i have only figured out this much.

$(".tablerow").hover(function(){
$(this)//on mouse enter
$(this)//on mouse leave
});

but i dont know what function to use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this just using CSS. Use a inset box shadow on a hover (or click for devices) and just change the color to whatever yellow/gold or other color you want to display. You can just use a normal box shadow for any glow/shadows you want outside the box

```
element {
  box-shadow:none;
}
element:hover, element:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #(color of the glow you want);
}
```

this gets you a shadow inside and outside

```
element {
  box-shadow:none;
}
element:hover, element:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #(color), inset 0 0 10px #(color of the glow you want);
}
```

Comment: thanks but i wanted to use jQuery because i have 9 divs with the same class if i use css then the whole 9 divs will glow.

so i was wondering to use the "this" keyword.

Comment: it wont change all the divs because you only give the div you are hovering over a :hover class, it works exactly like using 'this' in javascript

Comment: ok thanks i just came to know that there is no such direct effect for glow in jQuery, so i will go with the CSS

Comment: I would be surprised if there can be any opposition to this answer. I thought :hover only applied to the <a> element, mainly because I had read no different posts. This really will remove much un-necessary onmouseover code clutter for me.

Comment: If you want it to animate instead of appear just add transition: all .3s ease-in; to the element class!

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3's box-shadow. Something like this will probably work for you:

```
.glowMe:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px #ffffff; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffffff;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffffff; 
    box-shadow:0 0 15px #ffffff;
}
```

If you would like to toggle the hover with jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('.my-div-class').on('hover', function() {
  $('.my-div-class').removeClass('glowMe');
  $(this).addClass('glowMe');
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest that, if you're going to show vendor-prefixes, you should probably try and show them *all* (you've omitted `-ms` and `-o` (they've not switched to WebKit quite yet,s o far as I know), still: +1.

Comment: Ah, very good point! I forgot about -ms and -o. :) I work with the Bootstrap mixins mostly so usually I just do .box-shadow(0 0 15px #ffffff); :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a glow effect using the box-shadow property. This should to the magic without Javascript involved.

```
.tablerow:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this jsfiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/XBNkn/**

```
.box:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px #f2e1f2; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px #f2e1f2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px #f2e1f2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're asking for is animated glowing. I was able to come up with a solution that uses jQuery, jQuery UI, and a jQuery UI plugin.

You can check out the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberdash/mAmvE/2/

```
$( ".tablerow" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( this ).animate({boxShadow: '0 0 30px #ff0000'}, 200 );
});

$( ".tablerow" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).animate({boxShadow: '0 0 0 #000000'}, 200 );
});
```

The plugin I used is available here: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/